# Picking the nearest value from an array reflecting ranges

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that reflects rebate percentages depending on the number of items ordered:

```
$rebates = array(
   1 => 0,
   3 => 10,
   5 => 25,
  10 => 35)
```

meaning that for one or two items, you get no rebate; for 3+ items you get 10%, for 5+ items 20%, for 10+ 35% and so on.

Is there an *elegant*, one-line way to get the correct rebate percentage for an arbitrary number of items, say `7`?

Obviously, this can be solved using a simple loop: That's not what I'm looking for. I'm interested whether there is a core array or other function that I don't know of that can do this more elegantly.

> I'm going to award the accepted answer a bounty of 200, but apparently, I have to wait 24 hours until I can do that. The question is solved.

Comment: There is no such core function!

Comment: you know it is pointless to ask for one-liners when you dont specify the maximum line-length ;)

Comment: keys are not in a pattern? Thus we cant make a function

Comment: @Gordon: In before code golf.

Comment: @Gordon true :) Okay, *reasonably sized* one line.

Comment: @nerkn the keys have no pattern, but you can assume they are in rising order

Comment: I think this should be made a wiki.

Comment: @evolve the Community Wiki option doesn't exist any more. Plus, I'm not sure whether this is a CW candidate: There will be an accepted solution - the one I'm going to actually use

Comment: @evolve: If you think this should be CW, flag for mod attention and tell them to make it CW. Furthermore I don't see why this should be CW ;)

Comment: Given that there is no built-in PHP language construct to do this, why would you still use a one-liner? As you probably know that will kill readability. Using a function call is (imho) far superior.

Comment: @Niels yeah, true and good point. However, @nikic shows a nice, almost one-liner that is pretty readable IMO in his answer.

Comment: @nikic and @pekka the reason I thought it should be a community wiki is "1 liners" offer nothing really practical.  It isn't like you asked for the most efficient means of doing it, simply the most elegant "one-liner" which resembles code-golf more than anything practical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's another one, again not short at all.

```
$percent = $rebates[max(array_intersect(array_keys($rebates),range(0,$items)))];
```

The idea is basically to get the highest key (`max`) which is somewhere between `0` and `$items`.

Comment: I'm accepting this one because it works non-destructively, is the shortest approach, and doesn't need globals / closures. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think that the above one-line solutions aren't really elegant or readable. So why not use something that can really be understood by someone on first glance?

```
$items = NUM_OF_ITEMS;
$rabate = 0;
foreach ($rabates as $rItems => $rRabate) {
    if ($rItems > $items) break;
    $rabate = $rRabate;
}
```

This obviously needs a sorted array, but at least in your example this is given ;)

Okay, I know, you don't want the solution with the simple loop. But what about this:

```
while (!isset($rabates[$items])) {
    --$items;
}
$rabate = $rabates[$items];
```

Still quite straightforward, but a little shorter. Can we do even shorter?

```
for (; !isset($rabates[$items]); --$items);
$rabate = $rabates[$items];
```

We are already getting near one line. So let's do a little bit of cheating:

```
for (; !isset($rabates[$items]) || 0 > $rabate = $rabates[$items]; --$items);
```

This is shorter then all of the approaches in other answers. It has only one disadvantage: It changes the value of `$items` which you may still need later on. So we could do:

```
for ($i = $items; !isset($rabates[$i]) || 0 > $rabate = $rabates[$i]; --$i);
```

That's again one character less and we keep `$items`.

Though I think that the last two versions are already too hacky. Better stick with this one, as it is both short and understandable:

```
for ($i = $items; !isset($rabates[$i]); --$i);
$rabate = $rabates[$i];
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work without changing the rebate array.

But the array must be constructed in another way for this to work

```
$rebates = array(
   3 => 0,      //Every number below this will get this rebate
   5 => 10,
   10 => 25,
  1000 => 35);  //Arbitrary large numer to catch all

$count = $_REQUEST["count"];

$rv = $rebates[array_shift(array_filter(array_keys($rebates), function ($v) {global $count; return $v > $count;}))];

echo $rv;
```

Working testcase, just change count in url

http://empirium.dnet.nu/arraytest.php?count=5
http://empirium.dnet.nu/arraytest.php?count=10

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I'm accepting @salathe's approach because it's a tiny bit shorter and works without a global / closure, but this will work fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can manage so far:

```
$testValue = 7;
array_walk( $rebates, function($value, $key, &$test) { if ($key > $test[0]) unset($test[1][$key]); } array($testValue,&$rebates) );
```

Uses a nasty little quirk of passing by reference, and strips off any entry in the $rebates array where the key is numerically greater than $testValue... unfortunately, it still leaves lower-keyed entries, so an array_pop() would be needed to get the correct value. Note that it actively reduces the entries in the original $rebates array.

Perhaps somebody can build on this to discard the lower entries in the array.

Don't have 5.3.3 available to hand at the moment, so not tested using an anonymous function, but works (as much as it works) when using a standard callback function.

**EDIT**

Building on my previous one-liner, adding a second line (so probably shouldn't count):

```
$testValue = 7;
array_walk( $rebates, function($value, $key, &$test) { if ($key > $test[0]) unset($test[1][$key]); } array($testValue,&$rebates) );
array_walk( array_reverse($rebates,true), function($value, $key, &$test) { if ($key < $test[0]) unset($test[1][$key]); } array(array_pop(array_keys($rebates)),&$rebates) );
```

Now results in the $rebates array containing only a single element, being the highest break point key from the original $rebates array that is a lower key than $testValue.