# JavaScript conditional switch statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a way to write a conditional switch statement in JavaScript?

I'm guessing not, since the following is always going to `default`:

```
var raw_value = 11.0;
switch(raw_value)
{
    case (raw_value > 10.0):
      height = 48;
      width = 36;
      break;
    case (raw_value > 5.0):
      height = 40;
      width = 30;
      break;
    default:
      height = 16;
      width = 12;
      break;
}
```

If not, what should I use instead - a long if/else statement?

Comment: One nice solution would be an array, and a JavaScript version of this [recent PHP question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032753/picking-the-nearest-value-from-an-array-reflecting-ranges).... but that's not going to be trivial to port.

Comment: It's not THAT long of an if - else statement (if, else if, else). Pretty standard (and less indentation).

Comment: If/else takes less space, easier to read, less to write and less prone to self inflicted bugs..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), the evaluated value of the `switch` expression is compared the the evaluated values of the cases. So here the value of `raw_value` (number) is compared to `raw_value > 10.0` (comparison expression) and `raw_value > 5.0` (comparison expression).

So unless one of your case expressions yield a number equal to `11.0` or you use the `switch` expression `true`, you will always get the default case.

Just use a simple `if`/`else` instead:

```
var raw_value = 11.0;
if (raw_value > 10.0) {
    height = 48;
    width = 36;
} else if (raw_value > 5.0) {
    height = 40;
    width = 30;
} else {
    height = 16;
    width = 12;
}
```

Comment: And without the need for `break`, it's just as clean as the original.

Answer (score 161):

Like this:

```
var raw_value = 11.0;
switch(true) {
    case (raw_value > 10.0):
      height = 48;
      width = 36;
      break;
    case (raw_value > 5.0):
      height = 40;
      width = 30;
      break;
    default:
      height = 16;
      width = 12;
}
```

The expressions in the `case` statements will evaluate to `true` or `false`, and if that matches the `switch` condition... voilà. The `default` acts like an `else`.

Bonus: you can invert the whole logic by simply replacing `true` with `false`. With `if ... else if` statements, you'd have to edit every if-clause individually.

Comment: This should be the right answer, as it does what the OP asked in the style asked. However, I had a hard time the first time I saw a switch(true) statement.

Comment: Up voted and should be marked as the answer. Most programmers (or maybe just me) with server language exp. find the JS implementation non-intuitive. Its kind of weird starting the evaluated expression and working backwards!

Comment: Just a side note.  This is a clear example to not assume the guy with the most SO points has the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `switch` statement does not work used like that. However, this statement is not always simpler. For example, the `switch` version takes 15 lines:

```
var raw_value = 11.0;
switch(raw_value) {
    case (raw_value > 10.0):
      height = 48;
      width = 36;
      break;
    case (raw_value > 5.0):
      height = 40;
      width = 30;
      break;
    default:
      height = 16;
      width = 12;
      break;
}
```

and the "long" `if/else` version *only* 11:

```
var raw_value = 11.0;
if (raw_value > 10.0) {
      height = 48;
      width = 36;
} else if (raw_value > 5.0) {
      height = 40;
      width = 30;
} else {
      height = 16;
      width = 12;
}
```

So in your case, it is better to use the second one than the first...

Comment: Less lines of code is not objectively"better", since "good code" is subjective. Readability and ease of understanding are two other factors. I would perhaps add that this approach is better "if the goal is using as few lines of code as possible"

Comment: Based on how 'switch' is working, the first example will always hit default

Answer (score 1):

Don't try this at home, or take it too seriously, this is just for sugary fun...

```js
function conditionalSwitch(value, cond, callback /* cond, callback, cond, callback, ... */ ) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
    if (arguments[i](value)) {
      arguments[i + 1](value);
      return;
    }
  }
}



function test(val) {
  let width, height;

  conditionalSwitch(val,
  
    (val) => val > 10,
    () => [height, width] = [48,36],

    (val) => val > 5,
    () => [height, width] = [40, 30],

    // Default
    () => true,
    () => [height, width] = [16, 12]
  )
  console.log(width, height);
}


test(4.9);  // 12 16
test(5.1);  // 30 40
test(10.1); // 36 48
```

Comment: Erm, shouldn't this be in codepen or something, some place fun! Don't see the point of it being here...

Comment: @sij_a And thee years later, there it is :D

Answer (score 1):

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

You can use switch (true) and add cases that evaluate to boolean