# Add and Remove Class on Scroll Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class or remove class on getting element top by using <kbd>**[This DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/mLfAq/1/)**</kbd> . Here is the code as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sec1_offset = $("#sec1").offset();
    var sec2_offset = $("#sec2").offset();
    var sec3_offset = $("#sec3").offset();
    var sec4_offset = $("#sec4").offset();
    var sec5_offset = $("#sec5").offset();
    var sec6_offset = $("#sec6").offset();
    var sec7_offset = $("#sec7").offset();
    $("section").scroll(function () {
       if (sec4_offset.top < 100) {
            alert("You Are in Sec 4");
       }
    });
});
```

I also change the `$("section").scroll(function () {` to `$(body).scroll(function () {` and `$(document).scroll(function () {` but it didn't work!
Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `scroll` event of the `window` object, `scroll` event like the `resize` event is fired so many times, for efficiency you can throttle the handler, ie the handler is executed after a specified timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $sec = $("section"),
        handle = null;
    var $w = $(window).scroll(function () {
        // clear the timeout handle
        clearTimeout(handle);
        // throttling the event handler
        handle = setTimeout(function() {
            var top = $w.scrollTop();
            // filtering the first matched element
            var $f = $sec.filter(function() {
                return $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() >= top; 
            }).first().addClass('active');

            $sec.not($f).removeClass('active');

        }, 50); 
    }).scroll();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UTCER/

edit: If you want to add a class to another element, the most efficient way is using the `index` method:

```
// Cache the object outside the `scroll` handler
var $items = $('#menu li');

// within the `setTimeout` context:
var $f = $sec.filter(function() {
    return $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() >= top; 
}).first();

$items.removeClass('active').eq( $sec.index($f) ).addClass('active');
```

Comment: should be the accepted answer as it does exactly what OP wants.

Comment: this is kinda what I want but too confusing for me! what is handle and timeout for?

Comment: great! thanks for explain. but want if we what to add or remove a class to other element like navbar list <li> s? I mean you are adding class to section here which is working great but what if we want to add active class to a navigation?

Comment: @user1760110 You are welcome. You should have asked another question for that, however I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am going to try it

Answer (score 1):

use `$(window).scroll` for the scroll event listener

also you want to check sec4_offset.top against window.scrollY

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sec1_offset = $("#sec1").offset();
    var sec2_offset = $("#sec2").offset();
    var sec3_offset = $("#sec3").offset();
    var sec4_offset = $("#sec4").offset();
    var sec5_offset = $("#sec5").offset();
    var sec6_offset = $("#sec6").offset();
    var sec7_offset = $("#sec7").offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       if (window.scrollY >= sec4_offset.top) {
            alert("You Are in Sec 4");
       }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3UxP/1/)

Comment: Great thanks Patrick, can you please also let me know how I can use switch case instead of nested if here?

Comment: @user1760110, for that [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4082548/560593)

Comment: @user1760110, see undefined's answer it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).scroll()`

Here's what jQuery documentation says about scroll event

> > The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer has already been answered, but I'd like to provide an alternative answer on JSFiddle that might accomplish what you're looking for to a more dynamic extent. I would not ask to be voted as the answer, but simply noted as a reference for an alternative approach to this problem

http://jsfiddle.net/mLfAq/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offsets = [];

    $('[id^="#sec"]').each(function() {
        offsets.push([$(this).attr('id'), $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()]);
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++) {
            if(offsets[i][1] > $(window).scrollTop()) {
                console.log('You are in ' + offsets[i][0]);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
});
```