# How to test one variable against multiple number ranges

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am a student taking JavaScript. I am still new at this and I need some help

I am trying to create a script that tells people to enter a number which will be their average, and it will tell them what letter grade they get.

```
{
    alert("You got an A+, excellent!")

} else if (average   && 90-94) {
    alert("You got an A, congrats!")

} else if (average  87-89) {
    alert("You got an B+, great job!")

} else if (average  83-86) {
    alert("You got a B, good!")

} else if (average  80-82) {
    alert("You got a B-, good but push for an A!")

} else if (average  77-79) {
    alert("You got an C+, good but work harder!")

} else if (average  73-76) {
    alert("You got an C, work harder!")

} else if (average  70-72) {
    alert("You got a C-, work harder!")

} else if (average  65-69) {
    alert("you got a D, so poor!")

} else if (average <65) { 
    alert("F, see you next semester")

} else { 
    alert("Invalid, please try again")
}
```

Now the problem is, I do not know how to add multiple numbers into each section. I tried the && and commas but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this:

```
var score = parseInt(prompt("Please enter score (0 to 100)"));

switch (true) {
    case (score > 100 || score < 0):
        alert("Invalid, try again!");
        break;
    case (score >= 94):
        alert("You got an A+, excellent!");
        break;
    case (score >= 90):
        alert("You got an A, congrats!");
        break;
    case (score >= 87):
        alert("You got a B+, super!");
        break;

    // etc., etc.

    case (score >= 65):
        alert("D, so poor!");
        break;
    default:
        alert("F, see you next semester.");
}
```

Comment: When reading the question this is exactly what came across my mind

Answer (score 1):

```
} else if (average >= 90  &&  average <= 94) {
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var raw_value = 11.0;
if (raw_value > 10.0) {
    alert("...");
} else if (raw_value > 5.0) {
    alert("...");
} else {
    alert("...");
}
```

Check from num from higher to lower so that you do not need `&&` for range checking.

There is a way to implement this in a `switch` way, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082204/javascript-conditional-switch-statement).

Happy codeing.