# Alternate to If...else-if

Tags: java, if-statement

What is best way to reduce the line of code for many `if...else-if` statements. Apart from the `switch case`

```
if(a>0 && a<=5){
a=5;
}
else if(a>5 && a<=10){
a=10;
}
else if(a>10 && a<=15){
a=15;
}
else if(a>15 && a<=20){
a=20;
}
.
.
.
.
.
else if(a>95 && a<=100)
a=100;
}
```

I have gone through many posts but could not find the feasable solution.

Comment: for `5 , 10 , 15 , ... , 100` ?

Comment: if you dont have a regular difference in your live data, you could explore a [conditional `switch` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4082548/648350)

Comment: which language?

Comment: The question is for the Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = Math.ceil(a / 5.0) * 5;
```

This should solve the problem in your case. Use the ceiling function of whatever language you are programming in. Here is documentation for it in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-

Comment: His question doesn't quite give enough info, but I think your guess on what he was after was correct - and +1 ; good answer.

Answer (score 3):

for your problem it could be like this :

`a = Math.ceil(a / 5.0)*5;`

for more information look at [floor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_floor.htm) and [ceil](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_ceil.htm)

these are in `java` , i don't know what language you are using , but there might `floor` and `ceil` function