# PHP: Get two nearest neighbors from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032753/picking-the-nearest-value-from-an-array-reflecting-ranges) about picking the closest/nearest value from an array based upon a known value. What about if one wants to pick the **two nearest values** from an array looking at the same say?

```
$rebates = array(
   1 => 0,
   3 => 10,
   5 => 25,
  10 => 35)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rebates = array(
   1 => 0,
   3 => 10,
   5 => 25,
  10 => 35);


function getArrayNeighborsByKey($array, $findKey) {

    if ( ! array_key_exists($array, $findKey)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $select = $prevous = $next = NULL;

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $thisValue = array($key => $value);
        if ($key === $findKey) {
           $select = $thisValue;
           continue;
        }
        if ($select !== NULL) {
            $next = $thisValue;
            break;
        }
        $previous = $thisValue;

    }

   return array(
            'prev' => $previous,
            'current' => $select,
            'next' => $next
    );

}
```

[See it!](http://codepad.org/mRFHIOxx)

Answer (score 2):

By "two nearest" you mean the two smaller than or equal to the value of $items?

Anyway, starting from the answer to that other thread, which is

```
$percent = $rebates[max(array_intersect(array_keys($rebates),range(0,$items)))];
```

You can go to

```
$two_nearest = array_slice(array_intersect(array_keys($rebates),range(0,$items)), -2);
$most_near = $rebates[$two_nearest[1]];
$less_near = $rebates[$two_nearest[0]];
```

This can probably be reduced to an one-liner using `array_map`, but I think it's overdone already.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rebates = array(
   1 => 0,
   3 => 10,
   5 => 25,
  10 => 35)

$distances = array();
foreach($rebates as $key=>$item) {
    if ($key == 5) continue;
    $distances = abs($rebates[5] - $item);
}

sort($distances, SORT_NUMERIC)
```

Now you have an array with all the items in the array with their distance to $rebates[5] sorted. So you can get the two closest ones.
Or three closest ones. Whatever.

Just keep in mind that 2 items can have the same distance.

Comment: Conditions require being wrapped in parenthesis `(` & `)`.

Comment: No worries, and I like your honesty :)