# PHP: Calculate differences between array values?

Tags: php, arrays, diff

I am working on a pricing estimator, which are [based on the following array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032753/picking-the-nearest-value-from-an-array-reflecting-ranges):

```
$items = 7;

$margins = array(
   1 => 140, // Base price
   3 => 120,
   5 => 100,
  10 => 60);
```

By running the following line, I get the **nearest** value:

```
$margin = $margins[max(array_intersect(array_keys($margins),range(0, $items)))];

echo $margin; // Outputs 100'
```

However, if this function would operate on an array with a lot of space between each value, the nearest value would be really far away from the previous, resulting in a price that's probably going to make the customer sad...

How can I get a more precise result from this - like if I had manually filled out the gaps in the margin array, to cover all potential item quantities (which surely isn't efficient)?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be expressed using some sort of calculation involving percentages?

Comment: It isn't a defined constant percentage value for this calculation unfortunately...

Comment: @Industrial: If you don't have a rule how to create those prices, then we can't help you. For example you could say that the price decreases linearly. Or quadratically, or exponentially...

Comment: Math never been my strong side, so I'd prefer to enter the rough "design" of the pricing margin by an array...

Comment: Too bad computers are precision math *computers* and bad at "doing what you mean." :o) Sure, it's possible to interpolate the missing values, but I'm sure you'll get unwanted side effects from that. Continuing the above example the price should reach 0 somewhere around 19 products. Probably not what you want.

Comment: I already have a known "top" value (10) items, so interpolating should work well. I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a list of all numbers with something like `range(1, 10)`. Then loop through and fill the gaps :)

Comment: That's one way to go - but most certainly not efficient?

Comment: @Industrial Well efficiency is one thing but getting a working solution is another :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write `1 => 140, 3 => 120, 5 => 100, 10 => 60` I assume you mean "between 5 and 9, every item costs 100", so that **buying 7 items costs 7x100 = 700**. If that's the case, you can simply traverse the entire array once and get the resulting per-item price:

```
function get_price($prices,$real_qty) 
{
  foreach ($prices as $qty => $price) 
    if ($qty <= $real_qty) $real_price = $price;
    else break;
  return $real_price * $real_qty;
}
```

If the prices have been sorted by quantity (using `ksort`, for instance) then this function will return the total price for the provided quantity, doing very little work: at worst, it would look at every item in the price array once, and you probably only have a dozen or so items in that array.

On the other hand, if you think buying 7 items should cost something other than 700, then you have to explain how much it should cost and why, because it is not obvious from the problem data.

Comment: Hi Victor. Thanks for your answer. What I want is if a customer **buys 7 items** to get a margin calculated based upon the known difference above the current margin and the level above, relating to the number of items - 7

Comment: Listen... you're asking for a total price in the 420 - 700 range without saying anything about how that price should be picked (except that it should be within the range, and apparently the range bounds are not allowed). Do you have any rules about how the price should be picked, or do you expect us to make some rules up?

Comment: Hi again! Not clear what you mean with "range bounds not allowed)", but The rule is that the price should be interpolated between the known upper and lower values. Am I wrong if I would want the price to become 40% lower with 7 items then 5 items?